# Change value of SRC within .each function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the values of an element and then use it in another element within the same parent element using `.each()` function. However, this seems not to work. Here are the codes I am using. Please tell me where I am doing wrong.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="item">
        <td>
            <img class="thumbnail" src="http://www.domain.com/images/image1.jpg">
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="img">http://www.domain.com/images/image001.jpg</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
        <td>
            <img class="thumbnail" src="http://www.domain.com/images/image2.jpg">
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="img">http://www.domain.com/images/image002.jpg</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.item').each(function() {
            $(this).find('.thumbnail').attr('src', $(this).find('.img').html());
        )}; 
    )};
</script>
```

What I want to do is get the html of the `<p class="img">` (which contains the url to an image) and change the `src` of `<img class="thumbnail">` with that on page load.

Please help

Comment: `.attr` should be `.prop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.item').each(function() {
         $(this).find('.thumbnail').prop('src', $(this).find('.img').html());
     }); 
});
```

At the end you had `)};` instead of `});`. Also, `.prop` is preferred to `.attr`. quoting from the [`.prop` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in
>   specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the `.attr()` method sometimes
>   took property values into account when retrieving some attributes,
>   which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the
>   `.prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property
>   values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

---

It should be noted that in your specific situation, you are loading images *after* the page loads and *after* the jQuery fires. This causes a **huge** delay for the user. The thumbnails would load more quickly than a large image, but, at minimum, there is a flash of a broken image.

Answer (score 1):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ftW37/)

You had small typo error in your code. The closure of the functions `});` was like `)};` with inverted `}`;

By the way `.prop` is preferred instead of `.attr`, you can read more [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) about it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.item').each(function() {
            $(this).find('.thumbnail').attr('src', $(this).find('.img').html());
        }); 
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo error

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.item').each(function () {
                $(this).find('.thumbnail').attr('src', $(this).find('.img').text());
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

little error check at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HA5Zc/3/) , `use });  instead of )};`

Answer (score 0):

Working code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.item').each(function () {
        $(this).find('.thumbnail').attr('src',$(this).find('.img').html());         
    })
});
```